# Recording user input dynamic transform data on an object in Maya using Python

Tags: python, transform, maya

I am using Python and Maya 2015, and I was curious how you might dynamically record the transforms of an object while a user is draging the Maya transform widget.  I am also curious how, when using a script, you might have a user launch the transform widget and then the script would record the user input transforms for an object and use those numbers in other areas of the script. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's not an easy way to do it.  You can however fake it with  the not-very-well documented [draggerContext](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/CommandsPython/draggerContext.html) command.  Basically you'd create a draggerContext and make it active using `setToolTo`

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def on_drag():
    # handler for the drag action
    dragPosition = cmds.draggerContext( 'dragger', q=True, dragPoint=True)
    button = cmds.draggerContext( 'dragger', q=True, button=True)
    modifier = cmds.draggerContext( 'dragger', q=True, modifier=True)

    # print out the values...
    print dragPosition, button, modifier
    message = str(dragPosition[0]) + ", " + str(dragPosition[1])
    cmds.draggerContext( 'dragger', edit=True, drawString=message)

# Define draggerContext with press and drag procedures
cmds.draggerContext( 'dragger', dragCommand=on_drag, cursor='hand' );

cmds.setToolTo('dragger')
```

In this version you'd replace the printout with code to move the selected object and record the position.  `draggerContext` has options to allow you to get the correct projection from the cursor location into 3-space, though you'll have to spend some effort making sure the behavior matches what you want.

Comment: If you find it useful you should mark the answer as accepted for people who come across this in the future